# How does memory actually look for a C array?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, allocation

Say you have this C program

```
int main() {
     int *ptr;
     int ar[4];
     ptr = ar;
     return 0;
}
```

would the address associated with the label ar hold the base **address** of the first element of the array or would it hold the first element itself? If its the second then when you have 
ptr = ar; ar must evaluate to the address its representing as opposed to what's in that address... right?

I would appreciate any input on this

Comment: Why not just test it yourself? Compare `&ar[0]` to `(int *)ar`.

Answer (score 3):

`ar` is an array, which is distinct from a pointer.

However, in most situations (such as when you assign it to `ptr`), it **decays** to become a pointer, i.e. the address of the first element in the array.

Comment: So do the array's values live on the stack like the other local variables to the method?

Comment: @user1259909: Well, that's up to the compiler.  It's safer to say that local arrays act just like any other local variable.

Answer (score 0):

It will hold the address. To access the first element, use arr[0] or ptr[0].

Answer (score 0):

The value of an array name  is the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The *expression* `ar` always refers to an array object, and has the type `int [4]`.  Except when `ar` is an operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it will be replaced with ("decay to") an expression of type `int *` whose value is the address of the first element in the array.

So, given code like

```
printf("address of ar[0] is %p\n", (void *) ar);
```

the first thing that happens is that the expression `ar` "decays" to a pointer expression whose type is `int *` and value is the same as `&a[0]`, which  is cast to `void *`, and that's what gets printed.  The pointer value isn't stored at `ar`; it's computed from `ar`.

How this all gets translated to machine code is up to the compiler.  Here's what gcc on linux does with it (I saved your code to a file named `layout.c`, and compiled it as `gcc -o layout -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wa,-aldh=layout.lst layout.c` to get the following assembly listing):

```
GAS LISTING /tmp/fbgo448-tmp.359a6da/files/ccoNessg.s                   page 1


   1                            .file   "layout.c"
   2                            .version        "01.01"
   3                    gcc2_compiled.:
   4                    .text
   5                            .align 4
   6                    .globl main
   8                    main:
   9 0000 55                    pushl   %ebp
  10 0001 89E5                  movl    %esp, %ebp
  11 0003 83EC28                subl    $40, %esp
  12 0006 8D45D8                leal    -40(%ebp), %eax
  13 0009 8945F4                movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
  14 000c B8000000              movl    $0, %eax
  14      00
  15 0011 C9                    leave
  16 0012 C3                    ret
  17                    .Lfe1:
  19 0013 90                    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 2.96 20000731 (Red Hat Linux 7.2   2.96-112.7.2)"
```

The expression `-40(%ebp)` is the first element of `ar`; `-12(%ebp)` is `ptr`.  Line 12 computes the effective address of the item at `-40(%ebp)` and saves that value to `%eax`, which is then written to `-12(%ebp)`.

So in the context of gcc/linux, the answer to your question is that the address associated with `ar` contains the value of the first element.  Note that the answer could be different on a different platform.